# Trying to play a MP3 file using javazoom and getting an error saying "unable to load resource 'sfd.ser"

Tags: java, exception, jvm, mp3, policy

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.SynthesisFilter.load_d(SynthesisFilter.java:1626)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.SynthesisFilter.<init>(SynthesisFilter.java:75)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.Decoder.initialize(Decoder.java:283)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.Decoder.decodeFrame(Decoder.java:138)
    at javazoom.jl.player.Player.decodeFrame(Player.java:213)
    at javazoom.jl.player.Player.play(Player.java:120)
    at javazoom.jl.player.Player.play(Player.java:104)
    at exetersoundsystem.back.mp3_player$AdvancedPlayerThread.run(mp3_player.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unable to load resource 'sfd.ser'
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerUtils.deserializeArrayResource(JavaLayerUtils.java:146)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.SynthesisFilter.load_d(SynthesisFilter.java:1621)
    ... 7 more
```

I goggled it a bit and I was told to change some policy for some file, but I'm totally lost on what to change.

Comment: Information on what you were told would be helpful. A link, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a serial number - did they change the license?

I wrote a pure java mp3 player: [mp3transform](http://code.google.com/p/mp3transform/) - it is based on JLayer from JavaZoom when it was still LGPL.